# Return 5 items each time sequentially from array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, arraylist, array-view

I want to return first 5 items from array.

Once first 5 items are returned, then if I reexecute my function then it can return second 5 items from same array and so on.

How can I do this?

```
$myArray = [28,32,33,34,37,49,50,52,57,61,62,63,65,66,67,68,70,71,73,74,75,80,81,89];
```

I need output as below

```
Outputs:-
    first time $ans = [28,32,33,34,37];
    second time $ans = [49,50,52,57,61];
    third time $ans = [62,63,65,66,67];
    fourth time $ans = [68,70,71,73,74];
    fifth time $ans = [75,80,81,89];
```

Comment: You need to store count of runs somewhere. You can use cookies/session if you want to keep the position for each user, file/db/memory if you want to have it for all users together. Then you can use eg. array_slice function to get the part of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a class would benefit this situation:

```
<?php

class MyClass {
    
    private $pos = 0;
    
    private $data = [];
    
    function __construct($data) {
        $this->data = $data;
    }
    
    public function next($length = 5) {
        $offset = $this->pos;
        
        $this->pos = $offset + $length;
        
        return array_slice($this->data, $offset, $length);
    }
    
}
```

Example usage:

```
$class = new MyClass([28,32,33,34,37,49,50,52,57,61,62,63,65,66,67,68,70,71,73,74,75,80,81,89]);

print_r($class->next());
print_r($class->next());
print_r($class->next());
print_r($class->next(10));
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 28
    [1] => 32
    [2] => 33
    [3] => 34
    [4] => 37
)
Array
(
    [0] => 49
    [1] => 50
    [2] => 52
    [3] => 57
    [4] => 61
)
Array
(
    [0] => 62
    [1] => 63
    [2] => 65
    [3] => 66
    [4] => 67
)
Array
(
    [0] => 68
    [1] => 70
    [2] => 71
    [3] => 73
    [4] => 74
    [5] => 75
    [6] => 80
    [7] => 81
    [8] => 89
)
```

**UPDATE**

The updated code below works between executions of the script by serializing the object and persisting it to local storage. I also changed the way the data is retrieved by the script, in the example below it is read from a file called 'data', which makes the script more dynamic, in that you can pass different data sets to the script if needed.

Data (stored in a file called 'data'):

```
28,32,33,34,37,49,50,52,57,61,62,63,65,66,67,68,70,71,73,74,75,80,81,89
```

Script:

```
class MyClass {

    private $pos = 0;

    private $data = [];

    function __construct($data) {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function next($length = 5) {
        $offset = $this->pos;

        $this->pos = $offset + $length;

        return array_slice($this->data, $offset, $length);
    }

}

if(file_exists('class.ser')) {
    $class = unserialize(file_get_contents('class.ser'));
} else {
    $data = explode(',', file_get_contents('data'));

    $class = new MyClass($data);
}

print_r($class->next());

file_put_contents('class.ser', serialize($class));
```

The process for the script is as follows:

1. The script checks for a file called 'class.ser', if it exists then it deserializes the object contained within the file
2. If the object was deserialized then simply execute the `next()` method
3. If the object was not deserialized (as the file does not exist) then instantiate a new object by passing in the data from the 'data' file and execute the `next()` method
4. Finally, the object, with the now updated properties, gets serialized and stored back to local storage ready for the next execution

If you want to re-run the script from the beginning of the data set then you need to remove the 'class.ser' file that is created.

Comment: I used your method and its working fine for me, but it gives only first/all array(s) values at once while running the script. I wan't first array values while running script first time, second array values while running the script second time, ans so on... Can you please help me here?

Comment: I have updated my answer to show how it can work across multiple executions of the same script

Comment: Superb!!! got exactly what I want. Thanks RJK for your contribution. Also thanks for your brief explanation. :)